# Continuity of $g(t):=f(tx,ty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be a function and $M$ be a positive real number, such that for every $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$, the function $g(t):=f(tx,ty)$ is differentiable and $|g'(t)|\le M$. Then prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

We have,
\begin{align*}
|g'(0)|&=\left|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}\right|\\
&=\left|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(hx,hy)-f(0,0)}{h}\right|
\end{align*}
Since $|g'(x)|\le M$, so $\left|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(hx,hy)-f(0,0)}{h}\right|\le M$. Then how to proceed to show the continuity of $f$ ? Any hint. please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By MVT we get $|f(tx,ty)-f(0,0)|=|g(t)-g(0)| \leq M|t|$. This is true for all $t$ and all $x,y$. Now let $u=\frac x {\|(x,y)\|}$ and $v=\frac y {\|(x,y)\|}$. Then $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| =|f(tu,tv)-f(0,0)|$ where $t=\|(x,y)\|$ Hence, $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| \leq t M=M\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ from which continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$ follows.